# How do I change the background color of selected items of datagrid in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

So this is my datagrid, but if i select an item in my datagrid its color wouldnt change. the trigger doesnt work.

```xml
<DataGrid x:Name="dgAdatok" ColumnWidth="*" MinColumnWidth="100"  FontSize="9.5"  Background="Transparent" Grid.RowSpan="4" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,30,0,0" >
                <DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Purple"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#DA34AE"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#DA34AE"/>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGrid">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                    
                </DataGrid.Resources>
                
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: I just had to move the '''<Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                            </Trigger>'''
to the target type datagridcell

Answer (score 1):

```
<Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="#DA34AE"/>
       <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
       <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#DA34AE"/>
       <!-- Add trigger for IsSelected property -->
       <Style.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <!-- Change the background color when selected -->
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                </Trigger>
       </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

your are attempting to set a trigger on the `DataGrid` itself, which is not the correct target for the `IsSelected` property. You should modify the `DataGridCell` style to include a trigger for the `IsSelected` property.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to move the

```
<Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True"> 
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Blue" /> 
</Trigger>
```

to the target type datagridcell